# How to save configuration path of property and value at once using c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am working on an application where I need to save the **ConfigurationPath** and the value of the property into the database. Currently, if there are 3 properties in a class I need to save them separately I have to call the database to save changes for every property. I don't want to save it like this. Here is my existing code.

I want to achieve the whole KroneOptionsBase to be saved or updated in a single go using **OptionPatterns**.

```cs
public class KroneOptionsBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration key used when binding to an IConfiguration instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static string RootConfigurationKey => ConfigurationPath.Combine("Partners", "Krone");
}

public class PartLocatorOptions : KroneOptionsBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration key used when binding to an IConfiguration instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ConfigurationKey => ConfigurationPath.Combine(RootConfigurationKey, "PartLocator");

    /// <summary>
    /// If the part locator is enabled or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool? Enabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of manufacturer settings
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<ManufacturerOptions>? Manufacturers { get; set; }
}

public class ManufacturerOptions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ASPEN-specific identity for 
    /// the manufacturer.
    /// </summary>
    public int? Identity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Krone-specific brand code that 
    /// corresponds to the manufacturer.
    /// </summary>
    public string? BrandCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The identity for the associated location.
    /// </summary>
    public int LocationIdentity { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
private async Task updateMainConfigurationAsync(PartLocatorOptions configuration,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    try
    {
        var rootKey = KroneOptionsBase.RootConfigurationKey;
        var partLocatorRootKey = ConfigurationPath.Combine(rootKey, $"PartLocator");

        if (_options.NotifyOnSuccess != configuration.NotifyOnSuccess)
        {
            await updateDatabaseLevelConfigurationAsync(partLocatorRootKey,
                                                       nameof(configuration.NotifyOnSuccess),
                                                       configuration.NotifyOnSuccess ?? false,
                                                       cancellationToken);

        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _logger.LogMethodEnd();
    }
}

private async Task updateDatabaseLevelConfigurationAsync(string configurationPath,
        string key,
        object configurationLine,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        if (configurationLine != null)
        {
            var configurationResult = await _configurationRepository
                    .GetAspenDatabaseItemAsync(_databaseIdentity,
                        ConfigurationPath.Combine(configurationPath, key),
                        cancellationToken);

            if (configurationLine != null && configurationLine.ToString() != configurationResult?.Value)
            {
                if (configurationResult == null)
                {
                    configurationResult = new AspenDatabaseConfigurationItem
                    {
                        Key = ConfigurationPath.Combine(configurationPath, key),
                        DatabaseIdentity = _databaseIdentity,
                        Value = configurationLine.ToString()
                    };
                    _configurationRepository.AddConfigurationItem(_databaseIdentity, configurationResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    configurationResult.Value = configurationLine.ToString();
                    await _configurationRepository.UpdateAspenDatabaseItemAsync(configurationResult, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _logger.LogMethodEnd();
    }
}
```

For example in **PartLocatorOptions** I need to save the value of **Enabled** I have to get the configuration path like **Partners:Krone:PartLocator:Enabled** and add it as KeyName and get the value of **Enabled** and add it as ValueData.

I am also facing one more issue, for example, it contains manufacturer collection so what will be the solution for this part as you can see I have written a separate method to add the manufacturer list to the database. The database entries look like this. See the below image

[image]

Comment: Does anyone with a solution?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. This question has a lot of details that aren't relevant, and seems to be missing a few details that probably are relevant (e.g. what does the configuration repository look like? _Why_ do you have to call the database separately for each property? Can't you apply all the changes in a single call to `SaveChanges`?). Please try to narrow your question down to the specific programming problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, I think, the best way to save your manufacturer options list is to separate into a new table with following columns for the `ManufacturerOptions` : *Identity*, *BrandCode*, *LocationIdentity* + the foreing key of the option enable.

Same for other options `PartLocatorOptions`, where is the reference of the *ManufacturerOptions* table foreign key.

If you want to not save it in database, you can serialize into a JSON format either in a file, or on a cloud service or in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I'm looking at impacting multiple rows -- same table or across multiple tables -- I start looking at using stored procedures so I can make a single call to the database (efficiency) and the entire transaction can obey SQL ACID.